# JavaScript: Touch Events Working on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, events, drag-and-drop, touch

Is there any difference between writing JS touch events for iPad vs. iPhone? I have read a ton of documentation and as far as I can tell it should work the same way for both.

I have a drag-and-drop game, basically you grab a coin from under the dragon and drag it over to your vault. The dragging works on iPad, but not on iPhone. I'm trying to figure out why.

The game, for reference: https://codeeverydamnday.com/projects/dragondrop/dragondrop.html

The JS, abridged to just the relevant code for this question (with comments for clarity):

```
var dragndrop = (function() {
  var myX = "";
  var myY = "";
    // The coin's starting X and Y coordinate positions
  var coin = "";
    // The coin you start touching / dragging

  function touchStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      // Prevents default behavior of scrolling when you touch/drag on mobile
    var coin = e.target;
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var moveOffsetX = coin.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;
    var moveOffsetY = coin.offsetTop - touch.pageY;
      // Defines offset between left edge of coin and where you place your finger on it
    coin.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
      var positionX = touch.pageX+moveOffsetX;
      var positionY = touch.pageY+moveOffsetY;
        // Defines the X-Y coordinates of wherever you stop dragging
      coin.style.left = positionX + 'px';
      coin.style.top = positionY + 'px';
        // Updates the coin's X-Y coordinates with the new positions
    }, false)
  }
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
})();
```

If it helps, I am getting this console log error every time I click / tap on the iPad screen in the Chrome Dev Tools emulator:

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.`

This error doesn't seem to prevent the dragging from working on iPad, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the dragging not working on mobile? I tried adding a few things to fix the error based on other Stack Overflow questions I saw (ex. adding `touch-action: none;` in my CSS, but the error persisted).

Anyone see anything wrong in my code? I would love to get this game playable on mobile, as that's how most people would access it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the passive option is set to `true` for `touch-start` and `touch-move` events, and it being true means your function won't call `preventDefault` to disable scrolling.

Simply set the `passive` value to `false` to solve your issue.

```js
var dragndrop = (function() {
  var myX;
  var myY;
  var coin;

  function touchStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    coin = e.target;
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    const moveOffsetX = whichArt.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;
    const moveOffsetY = whichArt.offsetTop - touch.pageY;

    coin.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, { passive: false });

    function touchMove(e) {
      const touch = e.touches[0];
      const positionX = touch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
      const positionY = touch.pageY + moveOffsetY;

      coin.style.left = `${positionX}px`;
      coin.style.top = `${positionY}px`;
    }
  }

  document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, { passive: false });
})();
```

#### Edit

---

I looked at the code from the website you linked, and I realized that one reason the coin wasn't dragged was because of `touch` we were using and also because of the `once` option I passed to the `touchmove` event.

Whenever the `touchmove` event is used, we have to use the new touch to get the `pageX` and `pageY` positions on the screen, I decided to create a function for the `touchmove` event, because whenever the `touchstart` function is called, a  new `touchmove` event is registered because of the anonymous function handler.

So creating and naming a function for it will prevent the same function from being added.

Comment: That fixed my console log error; thank you! I have added the "passive: false" properties to those two places in my code and will test on my phone in a couple hours once the new code clears cache. I will mark yours as the Answer if it works! If nothing else it did at least fix the console log error.

Comment: Well, console log error fixed, but now the taps and drags aren't working at all on iPad or mobile (the taps/clicks used to work, just not the drags). I am going to take a look at the rest of my code to see if something outside of what I pasted in the description is affecting the functionality.

Comment: @KatieReynolds I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that edit out and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I've been working on this problem for 3 days straight and your code updates finally helped me.Thank you so so much! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I read your blog particularly about this project and all the progress you’ve been making. Love the effort. Good luck with the remaining 41 days and let me know if you’re stuck again :)

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much for taking the time to go through my blog! It has definitely been a roller coaster of ups and downs. I looked at your profile, I can't believe you are only 17! You are half my age but lightyears ahead of me already. You're going to go far!

Comment: Thanks a lot :D… looking forward to hearing from you soon.